Inserting a new row to pass data from php form
I have php code to send form data to Google Sheets and a tracking sheet. Is there a way to read the date in the rows already on the Google Sheet and insert the data in the correct location.  For example, if the sheet has 5/1/24 and 5/15/24 and the code is sending a new row with the date 5/10/24, I would like the row to go between the previous 2 rows instead of below the 5/15/24 row.
public function submitInvoice(Request $request)
    {
        $arr = $request->all();
        $request->validate([ 
            "officename" => "required",
            "workdate" => "required",
            "Completed" => "required",
            "self" => "required",
        ]);
        $provider_traker = array(
            'person_id' => $request->person_id,
            'officename' => $request->officename,
            'workdate' => $request->workdate,
            'Completed' => $request->Completed,
            'self' => $request->self,
            'first' => $request->first,
            'last' => $request->last,
        );

        PersonTracker::insert($person_traker);
        // Session::forget('provider');
        $sheetObj = $this->sheet($request->officename);
        if ($sheetObj) {
            $sheetData = $sheetObj->get();
            $workdate = $request->workdate;
            $dateObj = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $workdate);
            $monthName = $dateObj->format('F');

            $start_checking = false;
            $row = "";
            foreach ($sheetData as $key => $data) {
                if($start_checking) {
                    if(isset($data[0]) && $data[0] == "") {
                        $row = $key;
                        $row++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(isset($data[0]) && $data[0] == $monthName) {
                    $start_checking = true;
                }
                
            }
            $person = Person::find($request->person_id);
            $person_name = $person->firstname.' '.$person->lastname;
            $sheetObj->range('A'.$row)->update([[
                $request->workdate,
                "",
                "",
                "",
                $request->Completed,
                "",
                "",
                $request->first,
                "",
                $request->last,
                "",
                $request->self,
                "",
                "",
                $person_name,
            ]]);
        }


Loop through the rows until you find the first row after the new date. Insert your new row before this.
